# Do aircraft depressurise when taking off from a high elevation airport?

Tags: boeing-737, airbus-a320, cabin-pressure, air-conditioning

A jet aircraft generally maintains a cabin pressure of 7000-8000 ft during cruise. If the aircraft departs from a high elevation airfield, such as Quito (approx. 10,000ft), will the aircraft depressurise down to 7000-8000 ft?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11456/how-does-an-airliner-deal-with-cabin-altitude-at-an-airport-above-8000-ft?rq=1

Comment: Changing the cabin pressure from 10,000 ft to 7,000 ft would be pressurizing, not depressurising.